# Regex pattern priority who contain each other

Tags: split, regex-group

I'd like a regex that will help me to split the string by groups('id', 'description', 'category') where 'id' is integer, 'description' is custom words and 'category' is predefined words('C1', 'C2', 'C1 C2', 'C2 C3', 'C1 C2 C3' etc).
string samples:

1. "0 custom description text C1"
2. "25 custom description text C2"
3. "100 custom description text C1 C2"
4. "30 custom description text C2 C3"
5. "45 custom description text C1 C2 C3"
6. "45 custom description text any user defined category text"
   .....
   n(more that 1000). "2 custom description text any user defined category text"

in general, alternations in regular expressions are evaluated from left to right, so the leftmost alternatives are checked first, giving them priority):

```
(?<id>\d{1,3}) (?<description>.+) (?<category>(C1 C2 C3|C1 C2|C2 C3|C2|C1))
```

but it return wrong result - it detect category = 'C2 C3' in case of sample #5 (and i don't understand why this happens)

ps: actually the categories list is user-defined list which i load from file. this can be any strings(not actually C1, C2, C3 etc). there are more than 1000+ known categories... for now i am using solution like this:

1. add all known 'categories' to string array
2. sort 'categories'

   var sortedCategories = categories.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToArray();
3. for each category try to parse the given string

   foresch(var category in sortedCategories)
   {
   //use $"(?\d{1,3}) (?.+) (?({category})"
   var match = Regex.Match(givenString, mask);
   if (!match.Success) continue;
   //true category found. do something
   return;
   }

this logic is working but it need to much time.
i believe that the option where i can define the pattern priority is exist but i am weak in regex and need help :)
thank in advance

Comment: Which regex engine _detect category = 'C1' instead of 'C1 C2' (in case of sample#3)_?

Comment: first one ((?<id>\d{1,3}) (?<description>.+) (?<category>(C1|C2|C1 C2|C2 C3|C1 C2 C3))). actually it detect C2, not C1, that's was my mistake in problem description... any case it work incorrect. the main problem is that second regex also working incorrect and i do not understand why and how i can fix this

Comment: It's truly unfortunate that at time of string creation there hasn't been inserted an easily identifiable separator between description and category.

Comment: At first I thought 'C1 C2' were two categories, but now I understand it to be **one** of the _predefined words_ containing a space, right? Is there always only one category in a string?

Answer (score 0):

Before I explain why *it detect category = 'C2 C3' in case of sample #5*, let me suggest to use
[`(?<id>\d{1,3}) (?<description>.+?) (?<category>(?:C[1-3] ?)+)`](https://regexr.com/5nvnj) instead of the alternations. (Note the non-greedy quantifier `+?` in `(?<description>.+?)`.)

Now, why *that second regex* *detect category = 'C2 C3' in case of sample #5* - that's because the preceding `(?<description>.+)` has the greedy quantifier `+` which causes it to match as much as possible, and for the following  `(?<category>(...))` part the regex engine backtracks from the end of the string only as much as necessary, hence it matches the shorter alternative.

Comment: thank for you answer and sorry for not clear task description. actually the categories C1 C2 etc - it is just a simplified samples. actually the 'categories' strings list is known user defined strings (i load them from file) and they are not actually 'C1', 'C2', 'C3' as well. they are can be any user defined strings. the only one thing - i know all of them. that's why (?<category>(?:C[1-3] ?)+) will not help. i will fix the task description

Comment: Doesn't then just using the non-greedy `(?<description>.+?)` in your regex with alternations help?

Comment: hm.... i test few lines and looks like it work... i do not understand why it work but it work. i will test all strings in Monday and let you know :) many thanks

Comment: I (apparently unsuccessfully :-)) tried to explain above that if the `<description>` part of the expression is greedy, it matches as far to the right as possible, so that the `<category>` part only gets to match the shortest possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you wrote that *there are more than 1000+ known categories* and that *it need to much time*, I'm unsure whether this can be improved much keeping `Regex.Match`, since it needs more than 1000 alternatives. But you could test and compare the execution of a variant without the loop you are using, instead concatenating the categories into one pattern:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
                    
public class Program
{   public static void Main()
    {   string [] categories = { "C1", "C2", "C1 C2", "C2 C3", "C1 C2 C3",
                                 "any user defined category text" };
        var sortedCategories = categories.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToArray();
        var mask = @"(\d{1,3}) (.+?) (" + String.Join("|", sortedCategories) + ")";
        string [] givenStrings = { "0 custom description text C1"
                                 , "25 custom description text C2"
                                 , "100 custom description text C1 C2"
                                 , "30 custom description text C2 C3"
                                 , "45 custom description text C1 C2 C3"
                                 , "45 custom description text any user defined category text"
                                 , "2 custom description text any user defined category text"
                                 };
        foreach (var givenString in givenStrings)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(givenString, mask);
            if (match.Success) Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

If `$` is added at the end of the `mask` pattern, it's not even necessary to sort the categories.

That said, you could do without `Regex`:

```
            foreach (var category in sortedCategories)
                if (givenString.EndsWith(category))
                {
                    //true category found. do something
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: looks like '(?<description>.+?)' and '$'at the end of the mask pattern - it as all i need. this is really help. ps: foreach will not help in my case because i need to split my string to 'id', 'name', 'description', 'category' etc - not just check that the end of my string is much to 'category' pattern. thank you, looks like my problem is solved now

Comment: It's fine if the regex approach works fast enough. Side note: the above variant with `foreach` would still allow the string part to the left of the found category to be split into the other fields, with regex as well as otherwise.